# Jquery Accordion Menu not scrolling to anchor tags

Tags: jquery, tags, anchor, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an jquery accordion menu in my footer which is working great, except for the fact that when the submenu opens... the page does not navigate to the anchor link. Since this is in my footer, I am forced to scroll down to see the opened submenu. I want the page to automatically scroll down.

Any ideas why this isn't working? I also tried putting the id within the , but that didn't work.

My html:

```
<ul class="footer-offices">
<li id="#sanfran" class="one"><a href="#sanfran">text</a>
  <ul class="submenu"><li>office info here</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.footer-offices li > a").on("click", function(e){
if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
  e.preventDefault();  
}
if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
  // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
  $("ul.footer-offices li ul").slideUp(350);
  $("ul.footer-offices li a").removeClass("open");

  // open our new menu and add the open class
  $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
  $(this).addClass("open");   
}
else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
  $(this).removeClass("open");
  $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
}       
}); });
```

Comment: This is way too much code for an SO question. I suggest you trim this down to 10 lines or less of the most relevant code.

Comment: I removed the CSS... not sure if it was necessary to troubleshoot... I'm not sure what I can cut anything out of the jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this part:

```
<li id="#sanfran" class="one">
```

That ID should just say `sanfran`, without the `#`. The `#` in `<a href="#sanfran"` indicates that what follows is the ID, so `#sanfran` is redundant.

It should just be this:

```
<li id="sanfran" class="one">
```

Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem correct:

```
<ul class="footer-offices">
  <li id="sanfran" class="one"><a href="#sanfran">San Francisco Headquarters</a>
    <ul class="submenu"><li>office info here</li></ul>
  </li>

  <li id="boston"><a href="#boston">Boston Headquarters</a>
    <ul class="submenu"><li>office info here</li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Did you have an # tag in your ID that shouldn't be there?

You have this:

```
<li id="#sanfran" class="one">
```

And it should be this:

```
<li id="sanfran" class="one">
```

UPDATE:

Is the preventDefault in your javascript preventing the jump?

```
if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
  e.preventDefault();  
}
```

What happens if you remove that piece of code?

Comment: oops, sorry... I fixed that, but the page is still not jumping down.

Comment: Is the page live? So we can see it?

Comment: Is the preventDefault portion of your javascript causing it not to jump? See above.

Comment: Oh Wait.. I found something in the CSS that was affecting it. Thanks for your time Robert!

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks again!